# Shipping snapshots/sstables between Cassandra instances

Tags: cassandra

When I truncate a column family in Cassandra, it will make a hard link to the live sstables and then move on. Is it possible to take those snapshotted sstables and move them to a completely independent Cassandra cluster? I'd want the same schema in it, but it should store the stuff that was deleted from my main cluster (probably with a lower replication factor and such)

Is something along these lines possible/advisable/practical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it is indeed possible, using `sstableloader` or the `bulkLoad` JMX call, after rearranging the sstables file structure a bit.